# Java ProcessBuilder does not write line breaks

Tags: java, kotlin, processbuilder

I am running this (kotlin-)code:

```
val proc = ProcessBuilder("sed", "s/bla/blub/g").start()
val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(proc.inputStream))
val writer = proc.outputStream!!

writer.write("bla\n".toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
writer.flush()
// writer.close()
println(reader.readLine())

writer.write("blaa\n".toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
writer.flush()
println(reader.readLine())
```

I was expecting that this prints 'blub\nbluba\n', because I write 'bla\nblaa\n' to the stdin of sed, and sed is set to replace 'bla' with 'blub'. Instead, it does not terminate.

The problem seems to be that sed never writes anything, that is, the BufferedReader blocks on the first invocation of `readLine()`.

I think that the line break does not go through. Sed processes inputs line by line, so I guess the line never ends and sed never outputs anything. If I comment in the `writer.close()`, sed prints 'blub\n'. However, I obviously can not do the second write after a `close()`.

On the terminal, I can force sed to process stuff with no line break in the end by pressing Ctrl-D, and I don't have to do this if there is a line break. Why is this not working with the process builder?

UPDATE:

I replaced sed with my own program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  while(1) {
    printf("Write something: \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(char)*20);
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("I got: %s\n", s);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this does not replace bla with blub, but reading and writing works. It does not work any more as soon as I remove the `fflush(stdout)`. This is strange, because printing a new line should already flush stdout. However, I guess sed does not do an additional flush either. 
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to flush the writer after you write the line to it, by calling the `flush()` method.

Comment: Good thought! I can't belive I missed this. But unfortunately, it does not solve the problem. I'll update the code example with flush().